# Check if Python Polars DataFrame row value exists within a defined list

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I'm really new to Polars (v0.15.8)...so I really don't know what I'm doing.

I have a Dataframe and I would like to check whether each row from a column exists within a separately defined list.

For example, here is my list:

```
list_animal = ['cat', 'mouse', 'dog', 'sloth', 'zebra']
```

and here is my Dataframe:

```
df = pl.DataFrame([
        pl.Series('thing', ['cat', 'plant', 'mouse', 'dog', 'sloth', 'zebra', 'shoe']),
        pl.Series('isAnimal', [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]),
])
```

...which looks like this:

[image]

I would like the df to end up like:

[image]

I'm struggling my way through some examples and the Polars documentation. I have found two options:

1. use the pl.when function:

```
df = (df.with_column(
     pl.when(
         (pl.col("thing") in list_animal)
     )
     .then(True)
     .otherwise(False)
     .alias("isAnimal2")
))
```

However, I get an error:

```
ValueError: Since Expr are lazy, the truthiness of an Expr is ambiguous. Hint: use '&' or '|' to chain Expr together, not and/or.
```

or,

2. Using the docs [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/list_context.html), I tried to follow the examples to apply an expression on the elements of a list. I couldn't make it work, but I tried this:

```
chk_if_true = pl.element() in list_animal

df.with_column(
    pl.col("thing").arr.eval(chk_if_true, parallel=True).alias("isAnimal2")

)
```

...which gave me this error:

```
SchemaError: Series of dtype: Utf8 != List
```

I would appreciate any advice; thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [.is_in()](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_in.html#polars.Expr.is_in)

```
>>> df.with_column(pl.col("thing").is_in(list_animal).alias("isAnimal2"))
shape: (7, 3)
┌───────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ thing | isAnimal | isAnimal2 │
│ ---   | ---      | ---       │
│ str   | f64      | bool      │
╞═══════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ cat   | null     | true      │
├───────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ plant | null     | false     │
├───────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ mouse | null     | true      │
├───────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ dog   | null     | true      │
├───────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ sloth | null     | true      │
├───────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ zebra | null     | true      │
├───────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ shoe  | null     | false     │
└───────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you @jqurious; you are a champion! Worked perfectly. Can you recommend any Polars examples for me to continue my learning journey on Polars? Thanks!

Comment: I've learned from the tests: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/tree/master/py-polars/tests/unit -- issue tracker https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues -- and previous questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-polars